# Scripting Local Security Policy settings

Tags: windows-7, security

We have a bunch of Windows 7 laptops out in the field. They're **not** in a domain. We'd like to build a script/batch file that we can send to each machine and, when run, configure screensaver locking, timeouts, etc. I believe we'd want to do this via local security policy but am open to options.

Pushing and running the script aren't a problem -- we have an RMM tool that will handle that just fine. Just not sure what the script would look like. Any guidance?

Answer (score 1):

Those settings are stored in the registry, so that's what your script should be modifying.

Check out this [link over at the Technet forums](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/ITCG/thread/c8689a32-e43a-4a41-b481-bd0b07d2904a).  Seems like a big pain to me, especially to dive through the registry to figure out what keys to modify, and to what values.  (And, as a disclaimer, I've never tried this, so I can't verify it works... but it should.)

Answer (score 1):

Rather than trying to edit local security policies via the Registry, might I suggest looking into [Microsoft's Security Compliance Manager](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc677002.aspx)?  It is a free Solution Accelerator that lets you export, import and configure Group Policy settings.  In particular, there is an included command-line tool called LocalGPO that will apply a custom Group Policy configuration on non domain-joined computers.  The following Technet Magazine article has information on how to use LocalGPO: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/hh489604.aspx